# how do you send a get request to get dropbox access token in flutter, I am finding it really tricky to get the get request working

Tags: flutter, http, post, get, http-headers

I am quite new to flutter and have been struggling a lot with http post and get request, if you could please help me write the http get request to get the access token, it would be amazing. I am developing an android application, how do I get a redirect link that leads back to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple https call can be made through the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package. First, declare your import of the package at the top of your dart file:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Here is a general http get call:

```
var apiResponse = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(<YOUR-API-LINK-STRING-HERE>),
);
String responseBody = apiResponse.body;
```

This returns the response body as a string, which you can then JSON-decode to query through the objects in the response.

Here is an example of a HTTP Post:

```
var httpPost = await http.post(
   Uri.parse(<YOUR-API-LINK-STRING-HERE>),
   headers: {<MAP-OF-HEADERS-HERE>},
   body: json.encode(<String, dynamic>{<MAP-OF-BODY-HERE>}),
 );
 var jsonPostResponse = jsonDecode(httpPost);
```

What you're describing with Dropbox and a redirect link sounds more like OAuth2. You can read more about how OAuth2 works [here](https://oauth.net/2/), and there's even a Flutter package to help with integrating it available [here](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2).

Comment: thank you so much! yes I was talking about oauth2 and the links you gave helped a lot. But I still have one question, how do I get a redirect link for an android app?

Comment: Glad that helped. Generally a redirect link will be provided in the response body of the api call on success